# Deeply test nested return value of anonymous function from properties object with Jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, nested, jestjs

### Problem

I'm coding unit tests with Jest in a react app and I want to check if a function does correctly its (nested) job.
The function returns an object with three properties. Each property is equal to an anonymous function that returns a specific function. I cannot find how to test the specific function and its passed parameters.

This is how the whole function looks like

```js
const myFunction = (param) => {
    return {
        prop1: (value) => {
            return specificFunction(param.someProp1, value);
        },
        prop2: (value) => {
            return specificFunction(param.someProp2, value);
        },
        prop3: (value) => {
            return specificFunction(param.someProp3, value, true);
        },
    };
};
```

> I want to test the `return specificFunction…` lines

### Actual state

After reading the [JestJS docs](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/expect), I've tried a solution which works but without control to the passed parameters of the specific function.

```js
describe('myFunction', () => {
    it('should returns object with 3 properties that have an anonymous'
     + 'function that returns a specificFunction with specific parameters'
     + 'passed in', () => {
        expect(
            myFunction({
                someProp1: 'a',
                someProp2: 'b',
                someProp3: 'c',
            }),
        ).toEqual({
            prop1: expect.any(Function),
            prop2: expect.any(Function),
            prop3: expect.any(Function),
        });
    });
});
```

The test passes but without control

### Expected result

I want my test to check if the myFunction calls firstly the specific nested function and also it calls it with specific parameters like

```js
describe('myFunction', () => {
    it("should do the job (I don't want to write the whole (long) description)", () => {
        expect(
            myFunction({
                someProp1: 'a',
                someProp2: 'b',
                someProp3: 'c',
            }),
        ).toEqual({
            prop1: // Check if specificFunction is returned from the anonymous function
                   //and that the first parameter is 'a' and the second is the parameter from anonymous function

            prop2: // Check if specificFunction is returned from the anonymous function
                   // and that the first parameter is 'b' and the second is the parameter from anonymous function

            prop3: // Check if specificFunction is returned from the anonymous function
                   // and that the first parameter is 'a', the second is the parameter from anonymous function
                   // and the third parameter is a boolean set to true
        });
    });
});
```

I don't know if I'm trying to solve the problem the right way. I'm opened to any suggestion but I can't change the logic from the initial myFunction

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want something like:

```
const {prop1, prop2, prop3} = myFunction({
    someProp1: 'a',
    someProp2: 'b',
    someProp3: 'c',
})
expect(prop1(value)).toEqual(
// something here
)
expect(prop2(value)).toEqual(
// something here
)
expect(prop3(value)).toEqual(
// something here
)
```

Comment: Thanks, I have to remove a layer to do the stuff more easily and to execute the function !

It's a workaround from my initial request in the sense that I test the returned value from the executed specificFunction and not how it have been called. But it works for my case, so, thanks !

I suppose I have to mock the function to test how it have been called, do you have a way to do that ?

P.S : I'm a beginner in testing AND in JestJS testing, I read the doc and articles but I have some difficulties to figure out how to do some specific tests not 'trivials'

Comment: If you want to test how `specificFunction` has been called, you need to mock it. I'm not sure what your file structure is like, but the file that contains `myFunction` needs to import `specificFunction` from a different file. So that in your test you can `jest.mock('./differetn-file.js', () => { return {specificFunction: jest.fn() });`
and then you can import `specificFunction` in your test and make assertions on how it's been called. I hope that explains it.